# How to select a DOM element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I am trying to use `'querySelector'` or `'getElementById'` to select a DOM element
I am getting `Error: Value is null` vs `document.body` that works just fine. Pls let me know if I am doing something wrong.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './main.styles.scss';
import { createChart } from 'lightweight-charts';

// const twoC = document.getElementById('twoCharts');
// const twoC = document.querySelector('.twoC');
// const body = document.body;
const twoC = document.querySelector('#twoCharts'); 

const chart = createChart(twoC, {
  width: 1200,
  height: 600,
});

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <div className="trading">
          <div className="box one">1</div>
          <div className="box twoC" id="twoCharts"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="charts">
          <div className="box three">3</div>
          <div className="box four">4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: Where are you calling the getElementById? If you are calling it before the render method is called, it will throw an error. You can try calling getElementById in componentDidMount lifecycle method which gets called after the render method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React doesnt work that way, youll need to use a ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from 'react';
import './main.styles.scss';
import { createChart } from 'lightweight-charts';

const chart = createChart(twoC, {
  width: 1200,
  height: 600,
});

class Main extends Component {
  // Create the ref
  ref = createRef();
  
  componentDidMount() {
    // After the first render
    console.log(this.ref.current); // Gets the current HTML element thats rendered
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <div className="trading">
          <div className="box one">1</div>
          // Set the ref on this element
          <div className="box twoC" id="twoCharts" ref={this.ref}></div>
        </div>
        <div className="charts">
          <div className="box three">3</div>
          <div className="box four">4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

While your statements above are using `queryselector` and `getElementById` are correctly written, they are unable to find a matching lelement because the render function has not yet been called.

On the contrary, the document's body is already defined and rendered, hence it does not return a `null` value. What you could do as a workaround is this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './main.styles.scss';
import { createChart } from 'lightweight-charts';

const body = document.body;

const chart = createChart(body, {
  width: 1200,
  height: 600,
});

class Main extends Component {
  const one,two,three;
  getElements = () => {
  
   this.one = document.getElementById('twoCharts');
   this.two = document.querySelector('.twoC');
   this.three = document.querySelector('#twoCharts');
   //do something
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <div className="trading">
          <div className="box one">1</div>
          <div className="box twoC" id="twoCharts"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="charts">
          <div className="box three">3</div>
          <div className="box four">4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {this.getElements}
    );
  }
}
```